# Why am I getting an error on MAX_USERNAME

Tags: excel, vba, 64-bit, office365

I have a macro that gets the user ID (using the function belwo) when the Excel file is opened.  We have used this same code for years without any issue.  I have a user with Windows 10 (64 bit), Office 365, Excel 2016 (32 bit) and the line ("ebuff = Space$(MAX_USERNAME)") is throwing an error (can't find project?) message.

The MAX_USERNAME constant is defined as below.  Any suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for your help........

```
Public Const MAX_USERNAME As Long = 15


Function GetThreadUserName() As String

   Dim ebuff As String
   Dim enSize As Long

   ebuff = Space$(MAX_USERNAME)
   enSize = Len(ebuff)

   If GetUserName(ebuff, enSize) = 1 Then

      eEmpl = UCase(TrimNull(ebuff))
      eEmpl1 = Mid(eEmpl, 2, 5)

      Get_Group

      Exit Function

   End If

End Function
```

Comment: Use Option Explicit , declare all your variables.

Comment: I did not get that error when running the code.  (I'm on Office 365, Windows 7)  For a quick test, what if you add the variable inside the `GetThreadUserName` sub?

Comment: That particular machine was missing a calendar control and that was causing the issue.  Once I unchecked the missing reference, the error messages went away.  The user is going to get the calendar control installed on that machine and she should be good to go.  Thanks for your help........